# RxJava instead of Retrofit callback

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, android-recyclerview, rx-java2

I'm new to using RxJava and I have question about how can I change my new Callback from Retrofit on RxJava?

My working code is here:

```
Service service = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("lalala")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(Service.class);
```

And after that I write

```
Call<Board> call = service.getBoard("lalala");

call.enqueue(new Callback<Board>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Board> call, Response<Board> response) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(new BoardAdapter(MainActivity.this, response.body().getThreads()));
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<Board> call, Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });*/
```

But when I want to use it on RxJava, I do not understand how to do it. I tried.

```
service.getRxBoard(boardq)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Board>() {
                           @Override
                           public void accept(Board board) throws Exception {
                               recyclerView.setAdapter(new BoardAdapter(MainActivity.this, board.getThreads()));
                           }
                       }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                           @Override
                           public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           }
                       });
```

And it doesn't work. I get an exceptions:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
 Unable to create call adapter for io.reactivex.Observable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a call adapter factory with Retrofit that can create RxJava types.

[This is the library you need](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2). Add it to your build.gradle like so:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
```

Then when you build your Retrofit instance, add the adapter factory like so:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://example.com/")
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```